# Sqlite - Insert if Record Exitsts

Tags: sqlite, triggers, foreign-keys, constraints

I know this is a really basic question, but I can't seem to make it work. I have a table that looks like so:

```
 TABLE entry 
(
     "eID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "pID" INTEGER,
     "fID" INTEGER,
     "vidPath" TEXT )
```

And a related one here:

```
 CREATE TABLE "ftime" (
     "fID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
     "fName" TEXT );
```

I would like to have a trigger such that one can only insert a new record into the entry table against an ftime that already exists ie, the fID must already exists. I have come up with the following trigger, but it keeps failing for some reason:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_fid_exists    BEFORE   INSERT ON entry BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT from faceTime WHERE fID=new.fID;) END
```

Foreign Keys are not an option, sadly, because the automatic cascade doesn't seem to be working.

Thank you very much

Comment: Foreign keys work just fine. Did you read the [trigger documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)?

Comment: @CL.Read.Not in how I am using the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_fid_exists
BEFORE INSERT ON entry
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'no matching ftime record')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM ftime
                      WHERE fID = NEW.fID);
END;
```